# Will not show time that has a leading zero hour time

Tags: char, timestamp, ibm-midrange

From an AS400 data query, I am trying to convert a column into excel that is currently stored as 6 digit numerical into time shown as HH24:MI:SS. In Excel, it shows only times that do not lead with 0 (aka anything after 10:00:00). Here is what I currently have written:

char(time(timestamp_format(char(PS.B1AOTS), 'HH24MISS')), jis) AS "PFS Batch Time"

In AS400, it shows times without a leading zero (9:00:00) as opposed to 09:00:00. I think this might be the cause.

Comment: What is the format of PS.B1AOTS?  I have always leading zeroes in my tests

Comment: The format of the numerical dates are 9:00:00, 10:00:00, 13:00:00, etc in PS.B1AOTS. When converted, any time after 10:00:00 is shown and anything earlier is considered "blank".

Comment: For `format`, what is the **data type** of PS.B1AOTS?

Comment: As requested by @FredericP, we need more info, please provide the out put for the following query:
select DATA_TYPE, LENGTH, NUMERIC_SCALE,IS_NULLABLE from qsys2.syscolumns
where SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME = 'B1AOTS'
  and SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME = '<*FILE Goes Here>'
  and SYSTEM_TABLE_SCHEMA = '<*LIB Goes Here>'